# Query for Subscriber Click/Open Counts

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, subscriber

Can you anyone help me to write a query to get subscriber activity details from SFMC?

I am trying to update Lead score based on subscriber behavior, Unfortunately, I do not find the Lead scoring option in SFMC. So I am trying with query option to update manually. below is the actual requirement. Eg: A subscriber opens a specific email once, score them “x” value. If he clicked a specific email once, score them “y”, if more than once, score them “z” and so on.
I need subscriber activities like Email opened & Link clicked counts. I have tried with below query to get open details. It's working fine but I wanted to get click/open counts individual for all subscribers.

```
SELECT SubscriberID, SubscriberKey, ListID, EventDate, Domain, TriggeredSendCustomerKey FROM _open WHERE JOBID='x'
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on what exact subscriber details? Also here is the documentation on Data View: Subscriber https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_subscribers/

Comment: You should not post questions asking for someone else to do your work without attempting it, you should at least attempt the to build an SQL query as much as you can and if you are still having trouble, post your code with a detailed explanation of what is going on, I would recommend reading up on T-SQL/MS-SQL 2005 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/tutorial-writing-transact-sql-statements and SQL Query Activities https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/.

Comment: I have to update Lead score based on subscriber behavior, Unfortunately i do not find Lead scoring option in SFMC. So I am trying with query option to update manually. below is the actual requirement.

Eg: A subscriber opens a specific email once, score them “x” value. If he clicked a specific email once, score them “y”, if more than once, score them “z” and so on.

Comment: I need subscriber activities like Email opened & Link clicked counts . I have tried with below query to get open details. Its working fine but i wanted get  click/open counts individual for all subscribers.

SELECT SubscriberID, SubscriberKey, ListID,
EventDate, Domain,
TriggeredSendCustomerKey
FROM _open
WHERE JOBID='x'

Comment: @Shridhar update your question to include your code and explanation please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you have said now, you will need to join the **_Open** data view with the **_Click** Data view.

This will allow you to grab the correct information and activities you need, I have written a query that will get what you have requested so far plus the calculated fields you require.

### Calculated Fields

1. Email Clicked (Boolean Field)
2. Email Opened (Boolean Field)
3. Multiple Clicks (Number Field)

### SQL Query Activity

```
SELECT 
o.SubscriberID, 
o.SubscriberKey, 
o.ListID,
o.EventDate,
o.Domain,
o.TriggeredSendCustomerKey,
CASE WHEN o.EventDate <> '' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS Opened,
CASE WHEN c.EventDate <> '' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS Clicked,
(
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c2.EventDate) 
  FROM _Click c2
  WHERE o.SubscriberKey = c2.SubscriberKey 
  GROUP BY c2.SubscriberKey
) AS MultipleClicks
FROM _Open o
LEFT JOIN _Click c
ON o.SubscriberKey = c.SubscriberKey
WHERE CAST(o.EventDate AS DATE) > CAST(DATEADD(dd, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS DATE)
```

I have added a `WHERE` clause because if you do not tie down the data you wish to retrieve, you will end up querying the whole data view and that will cause significant performance issues. You can adjust the `WHERE` clause to whatever you wish to retrieve specifically.

I have not listed the target data extension but you I have noted the calculated field types you will need to setup and the remainder of the standard data view field types are located on the data views documentation page

Link: [**Data Views**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/)

Hope this helps.